# Cleartext icon Autocomplete Mui

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to show MUI Autocomplete clear text icon every time when I enter text it is showing when ever I select any option but not when I write anything.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just I know, the clear icon in MUI Autocomplete is not for clear text when you input, is clear for the options that the user selects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **freesolo** prop, where you can write anything and clear it with a clear icon, but one thing is you won't see the **No Options** text.

Comment: Yeah this is the issue